# How to format Spring REST Docs in response body with mockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc-test, spring-restdocs

I write my API documentation with Spring REST Docs.

Code example:

```
@Override
public void getById(String urlTemplate, PathParametersSnippet pathParametersSnippet, Object... urlVariables) throws Exception {
    resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(urlTemplate, urlVariables)
            .principal(principal)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(print());

    // do..
}
```

But the problem is that the result of the test is answered in one line. And understanding the structure of the returned data is very difficult.

Response example:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"creator":null,"modifier":null,"modificationTime":null,"creationTime":null,"id":100,"deleted":false,"name":"Name","description":null,"report":[{"creator":"System","modifier":"System","modificationTime":"2019-01-30T14:21:50","creationTime":"2019-01-30T14:21:50","id":1,"name":"Form name","reportType":{"creator":"System","modifier":"System","modificationTime":"2019-01-30T14:21:50","creationTime":"2019-01-30T14:21:50","id":1,"deleted":false,"name":"Raport"},"unmodifiable":true}]}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Further, I generate documentation from the answer received and in the documentation also unformatted JSON

What am I doing wrong? How to enable formatting for json?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're not in a position to configure your application to produce pretty-printed responses, you can have REST Docs do it for you prior to them being documented. This is described in the [Customizing Requests and Responses](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.x/reference/html5/#customizing-requests-and-responses) section of the documentation:

> Preprocessing is configured by calling document with an `OperationRequestPreprocessor`, and/or an `OperationResponsePreprocessor`. Instances can be obtained using the static `preprocessRequest` and `preprocessResponse` methods on `Preprocessors`. For example:
>
> ```
> this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk())
>     .andDo(document("index", preprocessRequest(removeHeaders("Foo")), 
>             preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())));
> ```

In the case above the request is being preprocessed to remove a `Foo` header and the response is being preprocessed so that it appears pretty-printed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did not think that the author of the library will answer me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try get `ResultActions` object from mockMvc and than get `MockHttpServletResponse` object. After that you can get all the values of the fields that came in response. In this case, you will not need to parse the string.

```
resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(urlTemplate, urlVariables)
    .principal(principal)
    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(print());

MockHttpServletResponse content = resultActions.andReturn().getResponse();
```

Also you can transform `MockHttpServletResponse`  object data to json. IUf you use Jacson, than write your custom serializer for this object, add it to `MockHttpServletResponse` and register in `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(MockHttpServletResponse.class, CustomSerializer.class);
mapper.registerModule(module);
String jsonResult = mapper.writeValueAsString(content);
```

`CustomSerializer` should extends `StdSerializer<MockHttpServletResponse>` and override `serialize` method.